# App with React frontend, NodeJS backend fails to connect with proxy server with API endpoint once deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, api-design

I recently finished a web app for a fake restaurant using React and NodeJS. Now that I've deployed it with Heroku, there's an error seemingly on the server side. When I try to import menu data from an API endpoint I created (which works fine locally), I get some variation of:

`GET http://localhost:3002/menus net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

My server.js file looks as follows:

```
const express = require('express');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  }

const menuRoutes = require('./api/routes/menus');

app.use('/menus', menuRoutes);

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log(` ==> API server now on port ${PORT}!`);
  });
```

Any idea where I should be looking to fix this?

Comment: Are you using `localhost` to try to reach Heroku servers?

Comment: Locally yes, but I thought that ```const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;``` prompts a switch to the environment port once deployed?

Comment: localhost is a special hostname which refers to the network of the current machine. Heroku apps are hosted on the herokuapp.com domain.

Comment: I've left localhost set as a proxy in the past and had it work just fine. If this is the problem, what should it be changed to instead for Heroku?

Comment: Heroku assigns urls to each project. Find it in your dashboard.

Comment: Is there a separate url that processes server requests?

Comment: What is the EXACT web request you are making to try to access your server???? You can find your Heroku app url at https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-app>/settings > Domain

Comment: It's an axios call: 
 axios.get('http://localhost:3002/menus');

Comment: Locally, React frontend is operating on localhost:3000, API at localhost:3002

Comment: Read this `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains` and this `https://medium.com/@huntersantanu/what-is-localhost-or-127-0-0-1-and-why-it-is-said-that-there-is-no-place-like-127-0-0-1-cb620cb6337d`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the domain for the app that is giving me trouble. That works fine. The only part that isn't working is the incoming data from my API.

Comment: You've told me that you're calling `axios.get('localhost:3002/menus');` to try to get data from your Heroku app. But localhost != Heroku. Until you verify that you ARE NOT calling localhost, I can't help you.

Comment: I've done a pretty massive overhaul on the whole app and have a setupProxy.js file now so the issue is slightly different now (504 error). However, the problem origin seems to be the same. Here's the problematic url if taking a look might make things easier: https://goodrestaurant.herokuapp.com/menu